# changing FLIPPER_VERSION on react native gives BUILD FAILED output

Tags: android, react-native, flipper

I'm trying to update my FLIPPER_VERSION from 0.33.1 to latest on react native (android) but it gives me a build failed output, how do i upgrade my FLIPPER_VERSION ?

gradle.properties

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.33.1 
#FLIPPER_VERSION=0.46.0
```

Comment: You mind posting the error log

Comment: have you tried what they say in https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/android-native

Comment: thank you, the error is not on the flipper_version already it was i forgot to set "multiDexEnabled true"

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: @srinivas You guys mind posting what error does it print when the build fails? Without it, it's hard to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @srinivas did you try to add the multiDexEnabled true ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help I have solved issue is this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787875/react-native-axios-or-fetch-when-i-called-post-method-get-method-working-fine

Comment: Because of build failing, I left that now i am unable to retest it anyway thanks for the help